# Trying to assign total # of results from JSON request

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jQuery to make a JSON data request. It's returning items based on a search query. All I'm trying to do is return the # of results to display on the page.

Here's what I'm doing when the search returns `success`:

```
if(data){ 
  var totalResults = data.length; 
}
$('ul.list-posts').before('<p>'+totalResults+' results for '+searchQuery+'</p>');
$.each(data.items, function (i, data) {
  var question_list = '<li><a data-qid="' + data.question_id + '"><span class=meta><b class=upvote>' + data.up_vote_count + ' Up</b><b class=downvote>' + data.down_vote_count + ' Down</b></span>' + data.title + '</a></li>';
  $('ul.list-posts').append(question_list);
});
```

But for some reason the `totalResults` var is returning `undefined`. I know it's trying to display the data and there's no data for `length`... But I'm not trying to display length from the data, I'm trying to use length to get the total number of results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let's see the response and the ajax code.

Comment: what does `data` show as in Firebug?  Are you able to see its values?

Comment: Although I wasn't able to solve this problem, I actually just realized that the API I'm pulling from returns a total results value in the data! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `data` is a valid object? Are you not looking for `if(data){ var totalResults = data.items.length; }`?

Does your `each` work fine otherwise?

You should also wrap the `each` inside the `if` and create a fallback with an `else`

```
if(data){ 
  var totalResults = data.length; 

  $('ul.list-posts').before('<p>'+totalResults+' results for '+searchQuery+'</p>');
  $.each(data.items, function (i, data) {
    var question_list = '<li><a data-qid="' + data.question_id + '"><span class=meta><b class=upvote>' + data.up_vote_count + ' Up</b><b class=downvote>' + data.down_vote_count + ' Down</b></span>' + data.title + '</a></li>';
    $('ul.list-posts').append(question_list);
  });
} else {
  $('ul.list-posts').html("<li>I wasn't able to retrieve data</li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the data is empty, try first to see if there is any object on it.